# can't update the score

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have tried coding many ways Ii can think, but none of them which don't give me errors, also don't update my score. All I have is a "Score:0" in the upper right corner of the screen and it should change whenever a laser beam fired from my ship collides with an enemy ship. Here is my last try. In my classes.py file, in Ship class constructor I have initialized the score:

```
self.score = 0
```

and set 2 staticmethods in the Ship class:

```
@staticmethod 
def set_score(score):
    for ship in Ship.List:
        ship.score = score
@staticmethod  
def get_score():
    for ship in Ship.List:
        return ship.score
```

which is a dumb way to point to my ship considering there is only one, but it's the only way I know and works without any scope errors. In processes.py file I have:

```
 for laser in classes.Ship_laser.List:
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(laser, classes.Enemy_ship.List, True):
        laser.destroy()

        classes.Ship.set_score += 50
        return classes.Ship.set_score()
```

and inside the classes.py file in GameScene class I put outside the while loop:

```
myriadProFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Myriad Pro', 30)
```

and inside the while loop:

```
show_score = myriadProFont.render('Score: %s' %Ship.get_score(), 1, (255,255,255),None)
screen.blit(show_score, (550,30))
```

All this is showing me is the score with the value 0(or with any value I put in the Ship class constructor at that line self.score = 0). I know the line

```
classes.Ship.set_score += 50
```

can't be right since set_score is a function,not a variable, but after about 30 tries to combine these elements and nothing updates the score I just don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here :

```
  classes.Ship.set_score += 50
```

I can't see how that will work - since set_score is a method, and not a property - what i think you need is :

```
  classes.ship.set_score(ship.get_score()+50)
```

also : instead of :

```
@staticmethod 
def set_score(score):
    for ship in Ship.List:
        ship.score = score
@staticmethod  
def get_score():
    for ship in Ship.List:
        return ship.score
```

this might work :

```
def set_score(self, score):
    self.score = score

def get_score(self):
    return self.score
```

That depends on whether you are using your ship class correctly - which is impossible to tell from the code snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry Tony,the score still does not update.Since ship is the instance and Ship is the class i made some adjustments:

Comment: within methods in your class self is the instance - regardless of what you might also call your instance externally. I think you need to do some debugging, is the score attribute actually updating within your instance ? when you return the ship.set_score() what do you do with that return value, since neiter your or my version of set_score returns anything.

Comment: It seems the score doesn't update in my instance.I dont understand your last question:the return value is not stored in set_score() and returned in get_score() and used in "the show_score = myriadProFont.render('Score: %s' %ship.get_score(), 1, (255,255,255),None)" line?Whatever value i pass in the constructor of the Ship class(self.score = 'value') is displayed and remains displayed no matter what

Comment: i think we need to take this offline - i am happy to help you if i can.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in another way:i deleted the Ship.set_score() and Ship.get_score() methods and erased the calls to them and deleted the self.score = 0 line from the Ship class constructor.In my PlayingGameScene class i initialized a score variable:

```
score = 0
```

outside the while loop, and inside the while loop i defined the condition which updates the score folowed by

```
score += 50
```

and

```
show_score = myriadProFont.render('Score: ' +str(score), 1, (255,255,255),None)
screen.blit(show_score, (520,30))
```

Thanks for trying to help,Tony!